# Executing php with crontab

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to run a php-script on a scheduled basis. So I'd thought crontab was a good idea. The server I'm using is on Linux which I'm not that familiar with. So the problem I'm having is, I don't know how make the script executable from php. I need to reference the script, or put it into a folder that can run php from the command line. So I don't know what path to give my crontab, for example:

```
5  * * * * var/www/some/path/script.php
```

I found some vague information about this php executable being found in

```
/usr/bin/php
```

But I can't find any php file in there, maybe I don't have it installed? My php5 and apache installation is in:

```
/etc/php5
```

So my question becomes, is there anyway to execute a php-script with crontab in any other folder, or do I just lack the php executable in usr/bin/php?

Comment: Stefan, what Linux distribution is this? Do you have the "regular" Apache/PHP packages installed - or do you use "Apachefriends" or
similar package?

Comment: The usual Apache/PHP. My phpinfo(); said Server Api: Apache 2.0 Handler.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Start by typing at a command line:

`whereis php`

Do this as the user that the cron job will be run under. This will show you the path to your executable. You can then use that path (if it's not already in your PATH variable) in your cron entry:

`5  * * * * /your/path/to/php /var/www/some/path/script.php`

**Edit:** you may need to install the `php5-cli` (Ubuntu package name) package if all you have is the Apache PHP module installed.  This will give you the binary executable that you can run from a command line.

Comment: whereis php gave me the answer "php :" Not very informative. I might have to consider installing that package then. I read something about running the crontab via Lynx for some reason if your php was installed in Apache mode and not CGI. My phpinfo(); said Server Api: Apache 2.0 Handler

Comment: Getting back "php: " on its own means that the executable couldn't be found - so you may need to install the package to get it.

Comment: Guess I'll go google it for a while on how to install it. I'll get back to you if that's ok? If I can't find anything useful that is. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problems.  Depending on your OS, you could use "apt-get install php5-cli" or similar but probably best to check your individual OS's package manager for details.

Comment: apt-get install php5-cli just gave me a bunch of errors, seems it can's find the .deb file it's suppose to find.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know I fixed it. I first had to run apt-get update in order to update the list from ubuntu repository. Then run apt-get php5-cli and then whereis php gave me the right path. Thanks alot for your help, you really saved my day!

Comment: How do you get mysql to work as well? I get a PDO error.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the wget command locally:

```bash
5  * * * * wget http://localhost/some/path/script.php
```

Comment: Never thought of this, that's genious!

Comment: This actually saved my day, i was stressed and every solution was not working but when i tried thus, it worked immediately..

Comment: @KiryamwiboYenusu I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 7):

Is this a Linux system?

In newer Linux distributions, there is
actually a convienient crontab-setup system
that doesn't require any entry in the crontab
by the user.
E.g in SuSE Linux, you have directories

```
/etc/cron.hourly/
/etc/cron.daily/
/etc/cron.monthly/
/etc/cron.weekly/
```

Just put an invocation script (konno_php_start) in any of these
directories, like

```
/etc/cron.hourly/konno_php_start
```

which is executable (chmod 755 or so) and
contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/some/path/
php  script.php >> logfile.txt 2>&1
```

and restart the cron daemon. Thats it.

From the logfile, you'll see if your php interpreter
will be found in the PATH. If not, change the
line in /etc/cron.hourly/konno_php_start
to

```
/full/path/to/php  script.php >> logfile.txt 2>&1
```

Regards

rbo

Comment: How do I restart the cron daemon?

Comment: SuSE: (as root)  "rccron restart"                           
Slackware-like:  /etc/init.d/cron restart                          
others: (google)

Comment: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 5097: Operation not permitted
...fail!

is what I got, but I'm not currently logged in as root. Do I need to be root to edit the crontab as well. Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions, I'm a bit new to the whole server thing.

Comment: Stefan, in order to handle system daemons, you need to be root. BTW. What Linux Version or Distribution is this?

Comment: You don't really need to restart cron daemon.

Comment: "Just put an invocation script (konno_php_start) in any of these directories" - No - these directories are for system maintenance scripts not application stuff. And you don't know WHEN in the hour/day/month/week the script will run. And the OP wanted to run his script every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

I had to find to follow a trail to find the executable:

```
andy@ararat:~$ type php
php is /usr/bin/php

andy@ararat:~$ file /usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/php'

andy@ararat:~$ file /etc/alternatives/php
/etc/alternatives/php: symbolic link to `/usr/bin/php5'

andy@ararat:~$ file /usr/bin/php5
/usr/bin/php5: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

so you need to include /usr/bin/php5 as the path to the php executable like so:

```
andy@ararat:~$crontab -e
#*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /home/andy/www/dev.com/corp_rewards_cron.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [env](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env), it will find and launch php for you:

```
/usr/bin/env php /var/www/some/path/script.php
```

Or you can place a shebang in your script.php (first line):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

then make it executable, and make crontab call it directly, like in your first example:

```
5  * * * * /var/www/some/path/script.php
```

Comment: Do I write this in the crontab?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do like this,

```
*/5 * * * * /path/gridmon2.pl 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

where in you .pl code you should grep using wget or something like this:

```
wget "/www/root/index.php"
```

or you can just do like this:

```
/usr/bin/wget "/www/root/index.php"
```

It's just my suggestion, I've only try wget to external site not locally and it works.

please try and revert.

Comment: short from for STDOUT is `> /dev/null 2>&1` instead of `1 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null`