# PHP error line 1: `<?php ?>'

Tags: php, linux, cron

I'm attempting to setup a very simple cron job on a web host. I have cron.php set to run every minute. Right now, for testing purposes, cron.php is simply this:

`<?php ?>`

And now, every minute, I'm receiving the cron email with these errors:

`//home/user/public_html/mysite/cron.php: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token newline`

`//home/user/public_html/mysite/cron.php: line 1: <?php ?>`

Is this server having a hard time accessing PHP from the command line or is there some other issue I'm not seeing?

Also, I've gotten similarly weird errors when trying to add in things like `echo "test";` or even just `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have no shebang line, so it is trying to execute the script using the default shell.

Add `#!/usr/bin/php` (or wherever PHP is) to the top of the script.

Comment: Where does this go? At the top of the crontab?

Comment: Got it, combined your answer with this one and got it going! http://stackoverflow.com/a/2689317/1242298 The shebang did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for cron jobs you normally have to specify the executable in the cmd line
/path/to/executable.php //path/to/file.php

the environment is probably returning the token error because it doesnt know what php is or what to do with it

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "#!/usr/bin/env php" as the first line in your .php file.
 env will find and launch php for you. Hope it works.

Comment: Be sure also that you use UNIX line endings, if you're editing the file in Windows

Answer (score 0):

Maybe thread is a litle bit old but I know it will help someone. I had the same error on cron jobs then I've created cron like someone visit my site, I added this line in the command:

```
wget http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/Cron.php > /dev/null
```

Change the address of webiste and path to your script.

Cind regards, Ivan