# Cron job not running the file

Tags: cron

I've problem with cron job.. I set cron job to running a file every five minutes, but thats not work... Cron job not running file, the code:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(1000000000000000);

    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/connect.php';

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

    $getinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM something WHERE game_id = '2'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($servers[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($getinfo)){

    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks all who try to help...

Comment: What does the entry in cron's config file or crontab look like?

Comment: /website/includes/something/thisfile.php

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689284/executing-php-with-crontab help? If this is the standard `cron` system, it is designed to run things like the `php` command; it won't run php source code directly, but you can provide the filename as an argument to the `php` command..

Answer (score 0):

Scripts rely on a special syntax to pick the interpreter to use. If you point the crontab entry directly at the file there is no way to determine the interpreter to use. If you look in any shell script you'll see a first line like:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

This points to the interpreter for the script. Point it at your php binary or call the script using

```
php /path/to/script.php
```

You also need to ensure the file has the executable permission set:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script.php
```

I found this page by googling "php run as script" which says roughly the same thing but with more details:

http://blog.johan-mares.be/ict/php/running-php-shell-scripts/

Comment: I don't have machine, I set up cron job throught cP

Comment: The steps are still the same. But I don't know how cP works or what your host allows you to do. You still have access to the file right? So use the shebang solution and use ftp or whatever you have access to to set the execute bit. Assuming cP doesn't do magic things, of course.

Comment: Cron job is OK.. In Cron job tab I have a more file which working good... But this doesn't work, I thing it mistake in code, more precisely in include.. Before I have same problem because I used session but I solved it. I was write include without $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and thats don't work, then I read on stackoverflow, username who create post "Cron job dont work" in code had include and some user is answer and said "Put this code front include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], if that don't work you say", I read that, and a put this code but again dont work, path is good but don't work...

Comment: Please update your question to make it clear that it's not a crontab problem, but a script problem. And link to the question that helped you partially.