# cronjob is not working Linux

Tags: php, cron

I want a script file to run once every minute.. I've written this command.

```
* * * * * php -q /home/<username>/public_html/cron.php
```

But, this cronjob is not working. whenever, I try to open this file `cron.php` in browser, it works fine.
I'm using Linux OS. Is there a way to debug it in order to come to know the error?

Comment: you can refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689284/executing-php-with-crontab, try to add the whole path to your php binary

Comment: @GreenSu, Sorry, I read that before posting the question.. that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Is there anything in the syslog indicating the source of failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added an empty line (new line) after your cronjob?

To debug:

Append 2>&1 to the end of your Crontab command.  This will redirect the stderr output to the stdout.  Then ensure you're logging the crontab's Unix command.

```
* * * * * php -q /home/<username>/public_html/cron.php; ls -la >>/var/log/cronrun 2>&1
```

This will capture anything from the Unix command.

A couple of additional hints:  Write out the environment variables by issuing the command set with no parameters.  And get the shell to echo each command with the set -x command.   At the top of your script issue;

```
set
set -x
```

For cPanel, you may want to test curl (in case it's installed on your server):

```
curl --silent --compressed http://www.your-domain.com/cron.php
```

So it should look similar to: http://grabilla.com/0450d-93d93a32-02ab-457c-ac1c-d2883552a940.html#

You may also want to try removing the -q from your command and see if it helps.

```
* * * * * php /home/<username>/public_html/cron.php
```

Comment: I'm doing this using `cpanel` cronjob option

Comment: I added 1 more option to the bottom of my answer (curl)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ubuntu as I am, use the full path.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/<username>/public_html/cron.php
```

Comment: I've tried this one as well. but, it also didn't work for me.
my complete path to `php` is `/usr/bin/php`

Answer (score -1):

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home//public_html/cron.php

Add the above line to the crontab file and run it . It will add a cronjob every minute