# Linux Crontab executes PHP script but this Script won't delete file

Tags: php, linux, file, cron

I'm running a PHP script via Linux Crontab. It runs correctly (verified using ps -ef). This script checks all the files in a specified directory and if the files don't meet certain requirements they will be deleted.

This sript works perfectly executed through Linux console (as root) but when It's executed by Crontab it won't work...

Suggests? Thanks!

PD:
- Permissions ->
- PHP Script (755)
- Target folder (777)
- Files to be removed (644)

Crontab Line:

```
*/1 * * * * php /var/www/server/close_con_watch.php >> /var/www/server/phpcronlog.txt
```

Comment: Please post the line that runs your script from the crontab file. You might find you're not running it with the correct permissions.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? We generally need more informative fault reports here... `:-)`

Comment: The issue could be that cron doesn't find the php executable.  Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689284/executing-php-with-crontab?rq=1 ?

Comment: Cron runs PHP Script correctly, I checked it in the process list. And are there other lines in Cron which are executed correctly (PHP too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked. The conflict was in the PHP Script.

My script checks files in a certain directory, the path to that directory was declared in a relative way. I declared the path in an aboslute way and It worked but I still don't get it... The PHP Script is in a fixed path, so all the paths declared in the lines of code should work as relative regardless where It's executed from... Am I wrong? Thanks everyone.

Why I'm confused:

- The relative path declared before didn't throw a path warning/exception.
- It worked perfectly when I executed the Script from console.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add the user/group to the Cron command, like

```
10 * * * *  root     /path/file.php
```

And make sure your file starts with

```
 #!/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: You can run as root, but it is a lot safer to run as a specific user having only the permissions you need.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem but thanks for answering

Comment: check your syslog. it should give some more info.