# How to update multiple random entries in one column at once in mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I wish to update the values in column `stemp` but all must be different and random between 30 and 70.

```
for($i=0;$i<=30;$i++)
{
    $temp= mt_rand(30,70);
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE sensor SET stemp= $temp");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798640/creating-a-random-number-using-mysql

Comment: BTW: You know, that you always update all entries, since you don't have a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use MySQL's `RAND()` function:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE sensor SET stemp=ROUND(RAND() * 40) + 30");
```

Putting this into a loop does not make sense either since you don't seem to have any kind of WHERE condition in your update statement so **all** records will be updated every time.

Comment: what can be done to keep on updating after every 10 seconds

Comment: Maybe run a cron job that executes a PHP script every 10 seconds? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689284/executing-php-with-crontab

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change your logic a bit:

First of create an array from 30 - 70 with [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php). Then [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and take an [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) from it. With this you have 30 elements, which you can loop through an update your db entries. Like this:

```
<?php

    $arr = range(30, 70);
    shuffle($arr);
    $update = array_slice($arr, 0, 30);

    foreach($update as $v)
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE sensor SET stemp = $v");

?>
```