# CronJob not working at midnight but its working if i set it at every 5 min

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have created cronjob but if I set it in once a day at midnight its not working. But if I set in every 5 min then its working. I dont understand whats the problem ?

Here I am attaching the screenshot of **midnight cron:**

[image]

[image]

I have tried to debug it by adding my mail id but I am not getting any mail if I set it on midnight.

Comment: just a thought try `00 00 * * *`

Comment: What means "not working"? is it not executed or you get en error?

Comment: no not executed even i added my mail id but m not getting any mail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing php with crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689284/executing-php-with-crontab)

Comment: @Alister No that is different thing i know cron job very well but this time i m getting this problem my command line is perfect my php script run perfect if i set cron on every 5 min. But it is not running @ midnight.

Comment: can you show us how do you define "5 min" cronjob ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cronjob line should look like this:

```
00 00 * * * /fullpath/to/your/script.php
```

(00 00 indicates midnight--0 minutes and 0 hours--and the *s mean every day of every month.)

```
Syntax: 
  mm hh dd mt wd  command

  mm minute 0-59
  hh hour 0-23
  dd day of month 1-31
  mt month 1-12
  wd day of week 0-7 (Sunday = 0 or 7)
  command: what you want to run
  all numeric values can be replaced by * which means all
```

More detailed:

```
Minutes [0-59]
|   Hours [0-23]
|   |   Days [1-31]
|   |   |   Months [1-12]
|   |   |   |   Days of the Week [Numeric, 0-6]
|   |   |   |   |
*   *   *   *   * home/path/to/command/the_command.sh
```

Comment: I can not select 00. If u select 12:00 midnight it comes only 0.

Comment: where do you rent your server?

Answer (score 1):

Cronjobs works on their environment, not yours. So it can't find php binary. look for php path with

```
which php
```

and change your cronjobs's "php" to printed path.

Comment: No path is perfect coz if i set on every 5 min a day it's working . But it is not executing when i set @ midnight

Comment: did you tried 00:01 maybe at 00:00 there is something else happens in system... isn't it acceptable after 1 min ?

Answer (score 0):

Cron to run daily midnight use like

```
00 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```

where `/usr/local/bin/php` is php path. and second `/home/john/myscript.php` is your script path.

There is many methods [listed here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/)  you can run PHP in cron.

Let me know if it don't solves your problem!

Comment: I can not select 00. If u select 12:00 midnight it comes only 0.

Comment: ok, I would suggest 
1. you should run  `/usr/local/bin/php` `/home/john/myscript.php` in your command prompt and then use  once a day but time `5 min` of your current time to test if it works properly or not.

Comment: You mean every 5 min ?

Comment: I meant, once a day at 3:30pm if your current time is 3:25pm. so you could test. also check permission of php file.

Comment: yes i did and its run. I did every 5 min, then i did once a day after 5 min as you said and its run. But @ midnight it is not running... :(