# PHP Cron job on MAMP / OSX

Tags: php, cron, mamp

I've tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689284/executing-php-with-crontab) but I still can't get my cron job working on my mac using crontab.

I've saved the following cron job:

```
*/2 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php http://localhost/social-api-examples/cron.php
```

And when I type `crontab -l` it shows me it's saved. But my PHP page isn't being hit. Is there a way to check if it's working?

Also, when I saved the cron job, it was to a temporary file location. Is that ok?

Comment: try using wget for http request otherwise call the php script directly using it location

Comment: sorry I'm not good with terminal, how do I do that exactly?

Comment: try using : */2 *   *   *   *   wget http://localhost/social-api-examples/cron.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was just to use "php" instead of the path to php:

```
*/2 *   *   *   *   php http://localhost/social-api-examples/cron.php
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should at least test the command you are trying to execute**

You cannot execute a URL with `php http://somesite.com/index.php` 
instead use wget if it's installed on your system:

`wget http://somesite.com/index.php`

Comment: You can use either cron **or** launchd. You don't need to install cron, it comes comes with OS X. The article you link to says that cron comes preinstalled and it doesn't mention launchd at all.

Comment: sure, the problem was actually on another place

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/php` is not an HTTP client: you need to pass it a *file path* not a URL.

Alternatively, if it is important to involve a web server, you can replace `/usr/bin/php` with an HTTP client such as curl or wget.