# Controller action as a cron job phalcon

Tags: php, cron, phalcon

I need to run a cron job to do a sql query and save the data in the database every 24 hours.

I have a controller called `GetproductsController.php` and the method I have to execute is `indexAction()`

I've tried to do it this way:

> 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,59 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent http://localhost:8080/myproject/getproducts/index

But I don´t know how to do it, If anyone knows how I can do it, I would appreciate it.

Regard!

Comment: `cd` is change directory it should at least start with `php`

Comment: can you give me an example? @nogad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689284/executing-php-with-crontab

My php path has always been /usr/bin/php.  The accepted answer to this question tells you how to find yours.  I'm not sure how to call a function thought.

Comment: In my case the path is good, but I don´t know how to execute the method indexAction() @tjfo

Comment: Why not create a page that runs the controller & action on it, then run a `curl http://pathtoyoursite.com/thefile.php` via cron? Always an option too ;-P

Comment: I mean in my case I use `curl https://mypage/getproducts/index` @Darren

Comment: Yes that's what you'd use @FabianSierra

Comment: but how I use the cron, I mean where I set the time for my cron job @Darren

Comment: Create a CLI command: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/cli.html. Controllers are inferred to be ran in a HTTP context. If you have a task that _both_ HTTP and CLI applications need to use, then extract it into a class of its own.

Comment: I am goint to try it, I am new in Phalcon, but I am goitn to check it! @MartinBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a cli bootstrap for your project.

- Default application class for web applications is `\Phalcon\Mvc\Application`. Instead, you should use `\Phalcon\Cli\Console` for cli applications.
- Default DI class for web applications is `\Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault`. Instead, you should use `\Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault\Cli` for cli applications.
- Default Dispatcher class for web applications is `Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher`. Instead you should use `Phalcon\Cli\Dispatcher` for cli applications.
- Default Router class for web applications is `Phalcon\Mvc\Router`. Instead you should use `Phalcon\Cli\Router` for cli applications.

Please note that the classes that I've mentioned are for Phalcon 2.0. I'm not sure if they are the same for Phalcon 3.

Here is the [documentation for cli applications in phalcon.](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/cli.html)

You can use the same config file with a few if statements. For example :

```
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    $di = new Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault\Cli();
} else {
    $di = new Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault();
}

if (php_sapi_name() === "cli") {
    $di->set('dispatcher', function() {
        $dispatcher = new Phalcon\CLI\Dispatcher();
        $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace('Project\\Tasks');
        return $dispatcher;
    });
} else {
    $di->set('dispatcher', function() {
        $dispatcher = new Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
        $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace('Project\\Controllers');
        return $dispatcher;
    });
}
```

You might be able to use controller classes with cli routing. But I would recommend using independent tasks.

After creating cli bootstrap file (let's call it cli.php) you can add shebang for php `#!/usr/bin/env  php` and make that file executable. Then you can run your tasks as `cli.php {taskname}`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like what you want to do is possible (calling a controller method from the cron).  Personally, I would try to use the Phalcon CLI from their documentation: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/cli.html

curl is another option.  For that, first determine where curl is located on your server with:

```
which curl
```

The result of this command will be a path on the filesystem such as /usr/bin/curl.  Use that result in the place of [path to curl] in the cron command below.

you would do:

```
59 23 * * * [path to curl] --silent https://mypage/getproducts/index &>/dev/null
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it doesn´t work!, I update my question!